# Why is my GLib timeout sometimes not destroyed?

Tags: glib

I use a timeout to perform an action periodically. Sometimes the timeout interval needs to be modified, so I set a new timeout and then destroy the old one by returning False from the callback. However, I have gotten bug reports that seem to pretty clearly show that sometimes the initial timer is not destroyed because the actions are running at both the old and new timeout intervals. Can you think of any reason this could happen? It seems to be an infrequent occurrence and I can not duplicate it.

Here's my python code for the callback function. There's essentially nothing happening between when I create the new timer (which succeeds) and when I return False (which seems to sometimes, rarely, fail to destroy the original timer).

Since this code was written I have modified it to store the timeout return value and to use `GLib.SOURCE_CONTINUE` and `GLib.SOURCE_REMOVE` instead of True/False, but that version has not been deployed yet. Nevertheless, I don't think those changes should be relevant here.

```
    def on_interval_timeout(self, user_data):

        # perform action here

        # update timeout if required
        if self.update:
            interval = (self.model.props["interval-min"] * 60 +
                        self.model.props["interval-sec"])
            GLib.timeout_add_seconds(interval, self.on_interval_timeout, None)
            self.update = False
            return False

        return True
```

Comment: Can’t immediately see any problems with that callback. What about the code which sets the timeout in the first place? Could that be being called twice? Is `self.update` modified anywhere else in the code? Is the code multi-threaded?

Comment: Good questions. I need to look into whether the initial job could be submitted twice... if that happened then perhaps multiple timers could be created and then only one might get updated. The only other place `self.update` is modified is where it needs to be set `True` to trigger the change... This code is not multithreaded (the entire project consists of several components running on many threads, but this part should just be a single thread).